# Связь между 2мя content_scripts разных вкладок в расширении хрома

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Итак на 2х страницах загружаю скрипты манифестом

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Empty",
"version": "1.0",
"icons":
{
    "16": "images/empty_16.png",
    "32": "images/empty_32.png",
    "48": "images/empty_48.png",
    "64": "images/empty_64.png",
    "128": "images/empty_128.png"
},
"permissions": [
    "https://web.skype.com/*", "http://flparser/*"
],
"content_scripts": [
{
    "matches": [
        "https://web.skype.com/*"
    ],
    "js": ["content_scripts/webskype.js"]
},
{
    "matches": [
        "http://flparser/*"
    ],
    "js": ["content_scripts/flparser.js"]
}]
```

}

В одном из них вешаю обрабочик события

```
console.log("1");

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, callback) {
    debugger;
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

в другом соответствено пытаюсь вызвать событие

```
var deleteLink = document.querySelectorAll(".bro-sendskype");
for (var i = 0; i < deleteLink.length; i++) {
    deleteLink[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        debugger;
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage('start');
    },false);
}
```

Код точно срабатывает, то есть и обработчики вешается и сообщение отсылается, но при этом не ловится и в консоль никаких ошибок не пишет, в чем может быть проблема? или мб есть проще способ ловить дом события с другой вкладки

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как удалось добиться, но со стороны кажется как будто костыль какой то мб кто предложит лучше способ.
В манифесте декларируем контект джаваскрипты у разных страниц по юрлу, так же бэкграунд нужен будет

```
    {
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Empty",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons":
    {
        "16": "images/empty_16.png",
        "32": "images/empty_32.png",
        "48": "images/empty_48.png",
        "64": "images/empty_64.png",
        "128": "images/empty_128.png"
    },
    "background":
    {
        "scripts": ["content_scripts/bg.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
       "tabs"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "https://web.skype.com/*"
        ],
        "js": ["content_scripts/webskype.js"]
    },
    {
        "matches": [
            "http://flparser/*"
        ],
        "js": ["content_scripts/flparser.js"]
    }]
}
```

далее с нужной нам страницы с которой исходит какое то действие вешаем на любой дом обработчик такое

```
deleteLink[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {chrome.extension.sendRequest({
            action: "brosend",
            login: broskype,
            message: text,
        });
    }, false);
```

теперь в бэкрагунде по сути просто ретранслятор который нечего не делает кроме как принимает этот запрос и рассылает во все вкладки еще 1 другой запрос

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request) {
    chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tab) {
        console.log(1);
        tab.forEach((tab) => {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, request);
        });
    });
});
```

теперь в контекте уже страницы на которю мы чето передаем обрабатываем так

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
    console.log(1);
    if (request.action === "brosend") {
        console.log(request);


    }
});
```